# C Zephyr SDK CRC16 Implementation

Tags: c, crc

I was looking around in the zephyr implementations and found this method for computing a crc16 checksum:

```
u16_t crc16(const u8_t *src, size_t len, u16_t polynomial,
        u16_t initial_value, bool pad)
{
    u16_t crc = initial_value;
    size_t padding = pad ? sizeof(crc) : 0;
    size_t i, b;

    /* src length + padding (if required) */
    for (i = 0; i < len + padding; i++) {

        for (b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
            u16_t divide = crc & 0x8000UL;

            crc = (crc << 1U);

            /* choose input bytes or implicit trailing zeros */
            if (i < len) {
                crc |= !!(src[i] & (0x80U >> b));
            }

            if (divide != 0U) {
                crc = crc ^ polynomial;
            }
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

And I tripped over this line here:

```
                crc |= !!(src[i] & (0x80U >> b));
```

I do not understand why they are using a boolean operator (!!) in this line. From my understanding this is what it does:
It basically does an implicit "casting" where it considers its operand on the right to be a boolean and negates it twice, which does not do anything besides making the output a 0 or a 1 depending on if the expression `(src[i] & (0x80U >> b))` was bigger then 0 to start with.
Is this correct? Why are they using the operator in this way?

Comment: `!!x` is equivalent to `x != 0`.  Also, `!!` isn't an operator.  It's two applications of the `!` operator, i.e. `!!x` is `!(!x)`

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks. can you imagine why they would go for this? is this a common way  to do this?

Comment: It's an idiom for turning values into canonical true (1) and false (0) values.

Comment: There is what I consider a design flaw with the way parameters are handled with this CRC. The initial value is cycled 16 times before including any source data bits into the CRC. This means that it can't be used to chain calls, where a second call would use the CRC returned from the first call to continue a CRC calculation over data split up into groups.

Answer (score 0):

It is inserting bit `7-b` from `src[i]` into the low bit of `crc`. If that bit is a `1`, which will be somewhere in the result of the `&`, the `!!` turns it into a `1` in the low bit, which is then or'ed into `crc`.

This is truly painful to look at. A better and cleaner way to do it is `crc |= (src[i] >> b) & 1;`, where `b` counts down instead of up. E.g. `int b = 8; do { b--; ... } while (b);`. Better still would be to just exclusive-or the byte after the loop, which does the same thing:

```
/* src length + padding (if required) */
for (i = 0; i < len + padding; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 8; b++)
        crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ polynomial : crc << 1;
    if (i < len)
        crc ^= src[i];
}
```

An optimizing compiler will unroll the `b` loop.